# Animated SVG image viewer for Linux

Tags: linux, image-viewer, vector-graphics, svg

I there an Linux Image viewer for animated SVG files?

Like this one:

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/raw/master/doc/screencast.svg?sanitize=true

[image: Demo]

Comment: Why is a web browser not good enough? What do you want from the viewer that a web browser doesn't provide?

Comment: Yeah but I use image viewer to view images usually, not browser.

Answer (score 4):

The file you've provided opened in animated form in Ubuntu Linux in both Firefox and in Google Chrome.

Comment: Yeah but, They are browsers, not image viewer.

Comment: If you want to use some software you can use GIMP and save the svg as gif. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/#step-5